# Can SELECT ... NOWAIT "deadlock"?

Tags: postgresql

The docs say (emphasis mine):

> FOR UPDATE, FOR NO KEY UPDATE, FOR SHARE and FOR KEY SHARE are locking clauses; they affect how SELECT locks rows **as they are obtained from the table**.
>
> With NOWAIT, the statement reports an error, rather than waiting, if a selected row cannot be locked immediately.

From this, I'm not sure if the following behavior is possible.

Imagine the same `SELECT ... NOWAIT` statement, which returns rows R1 and R2, is run from concurrent connections S1 and S2.

1. S1 obtains and locks R1.
2. S2 obtains and locks R2.
3. S1 tries to obtain R2, but it's locked by S2.
4. S2 tries to obtain R1, but it's locked by S1.
5. The lock on R1 is released due to S1 failing.

The question is whether step 4 can actually happen between step 3 and 5, or else steps 3 and 5 are performed atomically with respect to concurrent selects.

I'm guessing it cannot happen, since without `NOWAIT` (or `SKIP LOCKED`), this behavior would lead to deadlock (S1 waits for S2 to finish and release R2 while S2 waits for S1 to finish and release R1), but maybe such scenario would be resolved in some other way.

So, which are the guarantees here?

Answer (score 3):

In your scenario step 3 should fail, if it tries to obtain R2 with `NOWAIT` option. When it fails all locks of S1 are released immediately, and S1 must be rolled back. Thus, S2 may obtain R1 in step 4. This scenario can't deadlock.

If you try to obtain R2 in step 3 *without* `NOWAIT` option, step 4 will fail because of a detected deadlock, and S2 will release all of its locks immediately.

The guarantees are the defined behavior of locks in a relational database, as described in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-select.html):

> To prevent the operation from waiting for other transactions to commit, use the NOWAIT option. With NOWAIT, the statement reports an error, rather than waiting, if a selected row cannot be locked immediately.

*Reporting an error* means that the transaction is broken and must be rolled back. A transaction is atomic. To put it simply, this means that it may only be terminated with a commit if all the steps it contains have been successfully completed.

Comment: Thanks. But my problem is that this wording from the docs is also consistent with both transactions failing. It just says that the current statement fails, no that the other doesn't.

Is there _something_ that really, explicitly guarantees that one of the statement will succeed, other than looking at the code?

Comment: Yes, this is called the ACID paradigm. In your case: Each transaction is *atomic*. That means, that it completes successfully or it fails. And it is *isolated* – no transaction has access to the modifications of another transaction, which is not completed.

Comment: Sorry but I also don't see how ACID, which is very general, guarantees this. Both behaviors could be considered ACID-compliant.

Comment: Note: You have not to look into the code, because the answer of your question is indepent of the DBMS you are using. `NOWAIT`means report an error, if lock exists. Report an error means break the transaction. Break the transaction means free all locks it holds. This follows directly from the ACID paradigm.

Comment: Both scenarios are ACID compliant. The only difference is when they cause an error and force a transaction to terminate. And the behavior of `NOWAIT`, especially when it reports errors,  is well-documented.